# Place on.exit() within function but active for the script

Tags: r

In R, let's say I want to place the on.exit() command within a function, but want the on.exit command to apply only when the rscript exits as opposed to when the function exits. How would I go about it?

To rephrase I have on.exit() within a function, the on.exit() command applies to the local scope within the function. Is it possible for on.exit() command to apply to the global scope while still within the function.

Comment: How would you expect *any* function in *any* language to do anything after it's exited? It doesn't exist at that point.

Comment: Welcome! Could you describe what it is that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Cool, thanks for both responses. Will do.

Comment: First off apologies for my question. I'll be sure to improve my understanding of stackoverflow before my next question.

To rephrase, I was hoping to apply a function globally while still within a function.

So for example, let's say I want to hardcode some db credentials in a manner that will allow me to call on each connection and quicly initialize. I was hoping for something similar to the on.exit(dbdisconnect(conn)) command itself to be applied to the global environment as opposed to local environment so I will have both the connection and won't leave any loose ends.

Comment: Do you want your script to shut down your `R` session? If so, see `?.Last` . Since a script's environment (and scope) is the same as the console environment, it's hard to see how/why you want to separate the two.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks, `.Last` is what I came here for. Surprised it isn't referenced as a "See also" in `?on.exit`.